# ServiceMix JAX-RS - ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes

Tags: java, jax-rs, apache-servicemix

I have read through several of the posts with people having issues like mine, and tried several \ verified what I am doing but still no success.

First, I am following this tutorial...
https://vzurczak.wordpress.com/2014/09/30/web-applications-with-osgi-working-with-jersey/

But I am using ServiceMix, not Karaf. Should be similar enough though.

My POM.XML looks like this...

```
<project 
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>net.vzurczak</groupId>
        <artifactId>osgi-samples-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <groupId>net.vzurczak</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-with-jersey-as-a-bundle</artifactId>
    <name>OSGi Sample :: REST :: Jersey as a Bundle</name>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>

    <properties>
        <!-- 
            You need the version 1.18.1.
            1.18.0 may conflict with some OSGi containers
            (they use different and incompatible versions of ASM).

            This has been verified with Apache Karaf 3.0.x and Felix.
         -->
        <jersey.stack.version>1.18.1</jersey.stack.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.stack.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Import-Package>
                            javax.ws.rs.*,
                            com.sun.jersey.api.core,
                            com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet
                        </Import-Package>
                        <Web-ContextPath>rest-bundle</Web-ContextPath>
                        <Webapp-Context>rest-bundle</Webapp-Context>
                        <_wab>src/main/webapp</_wab>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My Web.xml looks like this...

```
<web-app 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
        xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
        id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <display-name>Welcome Page</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>net.vzurczak.sample.rest.internal</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- 
        The web context being "rest-bundle" (check the POM),
        the REST services will found under "rest-bundle/rest/".
     -->

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Trivial implementation is this:

```
package net.vzurczak.sample.rest.internal;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

/**
 * @author Vincent Zurczak
 */
@Path( "/get-data" )
public class MyRestResource {

    @GET
    public Response getDataToDisplay() {
        return Response.ok().entity( "Yes, it works." ).build();
    }
}
```

Here is stack trace...

```
2016-07-11 14:55:13,429 | ERROR | pool-8-thread-1  | RootResourceUriRules             | ?                                   ? | 212 - com.sun.jersey.jersey-server - 1.18.1 | The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
2016-07-11 14:55:13,429 | WARN  | pool-8-thread-1  | t-with-jersey-as-a-bundle - 214} | ?                                   ? | 64 - org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server - 8.1.15.v20140411 | unavailable
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:99)[212:com.sun.jersey.jersey-server:1.18.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1359)[212:com.sun.jersey.jersey-server:1.18.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180)[212:com.sun.jersey.jersey-server:1.18.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799)[212:com.sun.jersey.jersey-server:1.18.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)[212:com.sun.jersey.jersey-server:1.18.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)[211:com.sun.jersey.core:1.18.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)[212:com.sun.jersey.jersey-server:1.18.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790)[212:com.sun.jersey.jersey-server:1.18.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:491)[213:com.sun.jersey.servlet:1.18.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:321)[213:com.sun.jersey.servlet:1.18.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)[213:com.sun.jersey.servlet:1.18.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)[213:com.sun.jersey.servlet:1.18.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:376)[213:com.sun.jersey.servlet:1.18.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:559)[213:com.sun.jersey.servlet:1.18.1]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:161)[58:org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec:1.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:532)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:344)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:791)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.doStart(HttpServiceContext.java:222)[73:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:3.1.2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerImpl$1.start(JettyServerImpl.java:202)[73:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:3.1.2]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.HttpServiceStarted.end(HttpServiceStarted.java:1032)[72:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-runtime:3.1.2]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.HttpServiceProxy.end(HttpServiceProxy.java:422)[72:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-runtime:3.1.2]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.RegisterWebAppVisitorWC.end(RegisterWebAppVisitorWC.java:341)[201:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.1.2]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.model.WebApp.accept(WebApp.java:678)[201:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.1.2]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$WebAppDependencyListener.register(WebAppPublisher.java:237)[201:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.1.2]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$WebAppDependencyListener.addingService(WebAppPublisher.java:182)[201:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.1.2]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$WebAppDependencyListener.addingService(WebAppPublisher.java:135)[201:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.1.2]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:932)[karaf.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:1)[karaf.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)[karaf.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:183)[karaf.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:317)[karaf.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:261)[karaf.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher.publish(WebAppPublisher.java:101)[201:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.1.2]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebObserver.deploy(WebObserver.java:213)[201:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.1.2]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebObserver$1.doStart(WebObserver.java:175)[201:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.1.2]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.extender.SimpleExtension.start(SimpleExtension.java:58)[201:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.1.2]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.extender.AbstractExtender$1.run(AbstractExtender.java:266)[201:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.1.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)[:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)[:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)[:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)[:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)[:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)[:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_91]
```

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

If it's not an critical nor mandatory to use Jersey I would recommend you using CXF-JAXRS + appropriate blueprint namespace handler: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-configuration.html

This configuration is widely tested under Karaf and ServiceMix while Jersey support for these environments is missing.